# on the fly debug of BASH or SHELL scripts, pause inside loops

Tags: bash

When writing python scripts, I sometimes a quick look into loops, while pdb is great sometimes it is easeir for me to just print the value of a variable, and put a pause like statement after that:

```
print SomeVariable
raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

How can I do something similar in BASH scripts ? I would like to pause inside a while loop, and so far I am puzzled:

```
while read myline
do
   id $myline
   #here should be a PAUSE
   echo -p "Type enter to continue"
done < userNames
```

help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are use `read`

eg

`read -p "Please enter"`

if you want to debug your shell script, you can use `set -x` in your script, or run `bash` with `-x`

Comment: after a very long struggle I found out that on my OpenSUSE workstation is only working like this: read -p "Type Enter to continue... " mypause <&2

Comment: @Oz123: Since your loop is reading from stdin, you need to use an alternate file descriptor for your read. In your case, using stderr works.